# Find and print text in quotation marks from a text file with python

Tags: python, quotation-marks

I am a python beginner and want python to capture all text in quotation marks from a text file. I have tried the following:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter the full path of the file to be used: ")
input = open(filename, 'r')
import re
quotes = re.findall(ur'"[\^u201d]*["\u201d]', input)
print quotes
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nithin/Documents/Python/Capture Quotes", line 5, in <module>
    quotes = re.findall(ur'"[\^u201d]*["\u201d]', input)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: does it need to work across multiple lines? e.g., does it need to work for 'one two "thr\nee"' ?

Comment: The error is due to the fact that you are passing a `file` object, when `re.findall` wants a string. Use `re.findall(the-regex, input.read())`

Comment: Yes, it should work across multiple lines.

Comment: On top of everything else… you're trying to match a `unicode` expression against an 8-bit `str` (the file contents). You need to know what charset the file uses, and either `encode` the file contents or `decode` the regex.

Comment: Also, the regex you've written looks for a `"`, 0 or more characters from the set `^` `u`, `2`, `0`, `1`, or `d`, then a `"` or `”`. That doesn't sound like the same thing you described in your text. Are you looking for anything enclosed in either `"…"` or `”…”`? Or…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bakuriu has pointed out, you need to add `.read()` like so:

```
quotes = re.findall(ur'[^\u201d]*[\u201d]', input.read())
```

`open()` merely returns a file object, whereas `f.read()` will return a string. In addition, I'm guessing you are looking to get everything between two quotation marks instead of just zero or more occurences of `[\^u201d]` before a quotation mark. So I would try this:

```
quotes = re.findall(ur'[\u201d][^\u201d]*[\u201d]', input.read(), re.U)
```

The `re.U` accounts for unicode. Or (if you don't have two sets of right double quotation marks and don't need unicode):

```
quotes = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"', input.read(), re.U)
```

Finally, you may want to choose a different variable than `input`, since `input` is a keyword in python.

Your result might look something like this:

```
>>> input2 = """
cfrhubecf "ehukl wehunkl echnk
wehukb ewni; wejio;"
"werulih"
"""
>>> quotes = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"', input2, re.U)
>>> print quotes
['"ehukl wehunkl echnk\nwehukb ewni; wejio;"', '"werulih"']
```

Comment: Which one did you try? That last one?

Comment: After you assign your input variable, try to print type(input) and len(input) to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: If you are dealing with unicode, you might need to add re.U to the end of your search string, like I have done above.

Comment: What do you mean by input variable?

Comment: The variable that you call input in this line: input = open(filename, 'r'). Follow that with print type(input), len(input)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nithin/Documents/Python/Capture Quotes.py", line 4, in <module>
    print type(data), len(data)
TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()                       I use the variable data instead of input now.

Comment: Sorry. Add.read() to the end of that assignment to make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expressions you could try some python builtins. Ill let you do the hard work:

```
message = '''
"some text in quotes", some text not in quotes. Some more text 'In different kinds of quotes'.
'''
list_of_single_quote_items = message.split("'")
list_of_double_quote_items = message.split(""")
```

The challenging part will be interpreting what your split list means and dealing with all edge conditions (only one quote in string, escape sequences, etc.)